# Troubleshooting '413 Entity Too Large' Error in EKS Cluster with ALB and S3 upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I'm encountering an issue that I'm unsure how to address. I have an application hosted on an EKS Cluster. This application is exposed using an ALB, configured with the LB-Controller. One of the functionalities of this application is to allow users to upload files via an API and upload it to a bucket S3.

While this functionality generally works, it fails for certain projects, resulting in users encountering the error message 413 Entity Too Large.

To provide context, the application can successfully handle file uploads up to 125MB, but it crashes for files larger than 129MB.

The primary challenge is in the lack of logs. I've checked both the application logs and those within EKS, but have found no pertinent information. Initially, I suspected an issue with the ALB. However, after consulting with the AWS ALB team and sharing my logs, they couldn't identify any issues. According to their analysis, the requests are successfully reaching the target.

Any insights or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated ?

The stack AWS used by the application :
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "3.449.0",
"@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "3.290.0",
"@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "3.449.0"